# Setup mod_proxy on apache http server

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, protocol-handler

I wanted to reverse proxy a web service from my tomcat server using apache web server. I have modified the httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

ProxyPass         /ROOT  http://localhost:8080/ROOT
ProxyPassReverse  /ROOT  http://localhost:8080/ROOT
```

My Tomcat server runs on port 8080, now when I run localhost/ROOT, I get error 500 internal server error.

This last entry in the `error_log` is:

```
[Thu Jul 04 14:17:00.097359 2013] [proxy:warn] [pid 18980:tid 4476780544] [client 127.0.0.1:50525] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /ROOT. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

The last entry in the `access_log` is:

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2013:14:17:00 -0400] "GET /ROOT HTTP/1.1" 500 528
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8080/ROOT
 /ROOT

Comment: Any logs in the logs\access.log?

Comment: Hey, so that did not work, this is how httpd.conf looks like                 LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

ProxyPass         /ROOT  localhost:8080/ROOT                    ProxyPassReverse localhost:8080/ROOT /ROOT

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/439054/apache-reverse-proxy-no-protocol-handler

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/242650/setting-up-a-basic-mod-proxy-virtual-host

Answer (score 99, accepted):

So it took some time but I figured out the way to do it. There is one more module which needs to be loaded. This is what the httpd.conf looks like

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

ProxyPass         /ROOT  http://localhost:8080/ROOT
ProxyPassReverse  /ROOT  http://localhost:8080/ROOT
```

This works for sure. :)

Comment: `sudo a2enmod proxy`

`sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: THIS proxy_http is required!

Comment: Coming from a world where I used mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp for YEARS, you need to replace ajp with the http module in non-java configurations. The clue is this error in the Apache logs: AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL

Answer (score 69):

Since it's easy to overlook, pay attention to @muka's comment:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy  
sudo a2enmod proxy_http  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Make sure to enable both modules `proxy` and `proxy_http`!

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the other fine answers, if you're proxying to an https endpoint, you need to enable mod_ssl and add `SSLProxyEngine on` to your vhost